# error in dynamic textbox jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i'm trying to get values from autocomplete and binding them to textboxes it is working perfect on dynamic textboxes but not working on a static textbox. i'm sharing what i have done so far

JQUERY:

```
function bindData(auto, MFG, DC, PKG, BP) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $(auto).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
        data: { 'term': amount },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $(MFG).val(data[1].Manufacturer);
                    $(DC).val(data[0].DateCode);
                    $(PKG).val(data[0].PackageCase);
                    $(BP).val(data[0].Price);
                }
                else {
                    $(MFG).val('');
                    $(DC).val('');
                    $(PKG).val('');
                    $(BP).val('');
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#error').html(jqXHR)
        }
    });
};


$(function () {
    window.count = 0;
    $("#del").hide();
    $("a[id^='add']").live("click", null, function () {

        var l = $("#maintable > tbody > tr").length;
        if (l > 0) {
            $("#del").fadeIn('300');
        }

        window.count++;
        var PartNumber = "PartNumber" + window.count;
        var MFG = "Manufacturer" + window.count;
        var DC = "DateCode" + window.count;
        var PKG = "Package" + window.count;
        var Quantity = "Quantity" + window.count;
        var CustomQuantity = "CustomQuantity" + window.count;
        var BP = "BuyingPrice" + window.count;
        var BPUSD = "bpusd" + window.count;
        var AMTUSD = "amtusd" + window.count;
        var LTDAYS = "LTDays" + window.count;
        var Description = "Description" + window.count;
        var Note = "Note" + window.count;
        var btnAddID = "add" + window.count;
        var btnDelID = "del" + window.count;
        var table = $("#maintable");

        var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
            .append($("<td><input id='" + PartNumber + "' type='text' style='width:130px;' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + MFG + "' type='text' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + DC + "' type='text' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + PKG + "' type='text' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + Quantity + "' class='text-box single-line' data-val='true' data-val-number='The field Quantity must be a number.' data-val-required='The Quantity field is required.' name='Quantity' style='width:35px;' type='number' value='' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + CustomQuantity + "' class='text-box single-line'  name='CustomQuantity' style='width:35px;' type='text' value='' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + BP + "' type='text' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + BPUSD + "' name='ConvertedBP' readonly='readonly' type='text' value='' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + AMTUSD + "' name='ConvertedAmount' readonly='readonly' type='text' value='' /></td>"
            + "<td><input id='" + LTDAYS + "' name='LTDays' type='text' value='' /></td>"
            + "<td><select class='drop' id='" + Description + "' name='Description'>" +
                      "<option>Original ROHS</option>"
                      + "<option>ROHS Compliance</option>"
            + "</select></td>"
            + "<td><textarea class='txtarea text-box multi-line' id='" + Note + "' name='Note' placeholder='Any Note With Ticket'></textarea></td>"       
                ));
        tr.appendTo(table);

    });

    $("#del").click(function () {

        var l = $("#maintable > tbody > tr").length;
        if (l == 2) {
            $("#del").fadeOut('300');
        }
        $('tr:last').remove();

    });

    $("input:text[id^='PartNumber']").live("keyup", null, function () {

        bindData("input:text[id^='PartNumber" + window.count + "'" + "]",
            "input:text[id^='Manufacturer" + window.count + "'" + "]",
            "input:text[id^='DateCode" + window.count + "'" + "]",
            "input:text[id^='Package" + window.count + "'" + "]",
            "input:text[id^='BuyingPrice" + window.count + "'" + "]"
            );

        $(this).autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                                if (data.length > 0) {
                                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                        return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                                    }))
                                }
                                else {
                                    response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                },
            });

        $(this).autocomplete();

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="maintable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Part No
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                MFG
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                DC
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                PKG
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                QTY. Need
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                QTY. Offer
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                BP
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                BP(USD)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                AMT (USD)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                LT Days
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Desc
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Note
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="abcd" id="PartNumber" style="width:130px;" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="Manufacturer" name="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Manufacturer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="DateCode" name="DateCode" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="Package" name="Package" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Package" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Quantity" name="Quantity" style="width:35px;" type="number" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Quantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="CustomQuantity" name="CustomQuantity" style="width:35px;" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomQuantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="buyingprice text-box single-line" id="buyingprice" name="BuyingPrice" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BuyingPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="bpusd" name="ConvertedBP" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedBP" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="amtusd" name="ConvertedAmount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedAmount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                                <span id="error" class="error"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="LTDays" name="LTDays" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LTDays" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select class="drop" id="Description" name="Description"><option>Original ROHS</option>
<option>ROHS Compliance</option>
</select>
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea class="txtarea text-box multi-line" id="Note" name="Note" placeholder="Any Note With Ticket">
</textarea>
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Note" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Please guide me

Comment: give link to jsfiddle or ur site.

Comment: @PratikJoshi thanks for the comment i have posted the code in fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/AG74d/

Comment: @PratikJoshi did u check the fiddle?